# How to make in param a property of a class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was asked myself. How can I make a property of a class in function parameter? 
I wrote a pseudo code example to explain my idea.

```
private void UpdateCurrentGraphicSettingValue(Dropdown pDropdown, ??? pThing)
{
    if(pDropdown.value == 0)
    {
        CurrentGraphicsSetting.pThing = LowGraphicsSetting.pThing
    }
}
```

If you have any suggestion, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer, please?

Comment: You could use a `generic`, or the `dynamic` type.

Comment: Yeah... It make sense ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest something like this instead?

If there are any parts you don't understand, I'll explain.

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    public GraphicSettings CurrentGraphicsSetting;
    public GraphicSettings LowGraphicsSetting = new GraphicSettings() { pThing1 = 23, pThing2 = "test23" };
    public GraphicSettings HighGraphicsSetting = new GraphicSettings() { pThing1 = 2300, pThing2 = "test23sd" };

    public class GraphicSettings
    {
        public int pThing1 = 0;
        public string pThing2 = "test";
    }

    private void UpdateCurrentGraphicSettingValue(Dropdown pDropdown)
    {
        if (pDropdown.value == 0)
        {
            CurrentGraphicsSetting = LowGraphicsSetting;
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentGraphicsSetting = HighGraphicsSetting;
        }

        ApplyGraphicSettings();
    }

    private void ApplyGraphicSettings()
    {
        SomeSetting = CurrentGraphicsSetting.pThing1;
        SomeOtherSetting = CurrentGraphicsSetting.pThing2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your help i finally solved my problem... Just like this :

```
private void UpdateCurrentGraphicSettingValue(Dropdown pDropdown, ref int p1, ref int p2)
{
    if(pDropdown.value == 0)
    {
        p1 = p2;
    }

UpdateCurrentGraphicSettingValue(myDropdown, ref CurrentGraphic.pixelLightCount, ref LowGraphic.pixelLightCount)
```